# Filling array with numbers from given range so that sum of adjacent numbers is square number

Tags: algorithms, numbers

**Problem:** Fill all the cells using distinct numbers from <1,25> set, so that sum of two adjacent cells is a square number.

[image]

(source: http://grymat.im.pwr.wroc.pl/etap1/zad1etp1213.pdf; numbers 20 and 13 have been given)

I've already solved this problem analytically and now I would like to approach it using an algorithm.

**I would like to know how should I approach these kind of problems in general (not a solution, just a point for me to start).**

Comment: i'm curious: why are the cells arranged with two bumps but not in a horizontal straight line?

Comment: When in doubt just bruteforce it.  Try every combination and test that it satisfies your condition.  You could speed things up by testing adjacent cells as you produce the combinations.

Comment: @mauris - I'm guessing it's because the cells better fit the A4 page layout this way.

Comment: @Asaf, I know it can be done using BF but I'm looking for something more sophisticated.

Comment: Why has this question been downvoted?

Comment: @REACHUS Maybe it's because it's more of a question for stackoverflow than stackexchange.  That's only a guess.  Here's another suggestion that's less brute-force (you may disagree): first find every pair of numbers where they add to be a square number and now attempt to place the pairs one after the other until you use up all the numbers between 1-25?

Comment: Define "adjacent". If 2 cells are vertical would they be considered adjacent? Also, could a number appear more than once? Also, is the square of 2 cells bounded? Do you assume left to right direction only?

Comment: @EmmadKareem Adjacent: you can take any pair of cells that are next to each other (directly; including vertical). Numbers can appear only once. Solution should work in both directions. What do you mean by 'bounded square of 2 cells'?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, what you have already answered makes the problem hard enough!

Comment: For the left most 3 vertical cells, with the top most =20, the only number you could use below 20 (satisfying your conditions) is 21. If you use as the middle cell you get 20, 21 but there is no integer that can be placed in the cell blow the one with value 21 satisfying your conditions (>0 and less than 26) - Any hints?

Comment: 20 + 21 = 41, that's not square. He could use 5 or 16 there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to recognize that this is actually another problem- the Travelling Salesman.

Each number between 1-25 is a vertex. If x + y = square, then there is an edge between x and y. For n numbers, you can build this graph in O(n^2). Now visit each node so that no node is visited more than once. This is NP-Complete and the essence of TSP.

Once you recognize this variant, you can start by adapting solutions to TSP to your specific instance of it.

Comment: TSP requires you to return to the original point, this doesn't. TSP is equivalent to finding a Hamiltonian cycle, this is equivalent to finding a Hamiltonian path (of course the difference is really just superficial).